# Flickering ListView in virtual mode

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, virtualmode

I found a not so funny bug in the default ListView (not owner drawed!). It flickers **heavily** when items are added constantly into it (by using `Timer` to example) and user is trying to see items slightly **away from selected item** (scrolled either up or down).

### Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is some code to reproduce it:

- Create WindowsFormsApplication1;
- set form `WindowState` to Maximized;
- put on form timer1, set `Enabled` to true;
- put on form listView1:

  ```
      this.listView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
      this.listView1.VirtualMode = true;
  ```
- add one column;
- add event

  ```
      this.listView1.RetrieveVirtualItem += new System.Windows.Forms.RetrieveVirtualItemEventHandler(this.listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem);
  ```
- and finally

  ```
  private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
  {
      e.Item = new ListViewItem(e.ItemIndex.ToString());
  }

  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      listView1.VirtualListSize++;
  }
  ```

---

Now run it and wait until scrollbar on listview will appears (as timer will add enough items), then:

- Select one of the first items in the listview (with mouse or keys), then scroll **down** by using scrollbar or mouse wheel, so that selected item will go outside of current view (up). The more you scroll down, the heavier flickering will become! And look at what scrollbar is doing ?!?!?
- Similar effect appears if scrolling selected item down.

---

### Question

How do I deal with it? Idea is to have sort of constantly updating log window with possibility to stop auto-scrolling and go up/down to investigate events in close proximity. But with that *kek-effect* it is just not possible!

Comment: How about the `Interval` of your `Timer`?

Comment: @KingKing, it's default `100`. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Sinatr some flicker can happen much if the `Interval` of timer is small, however even the smallest `1` doesn't matter with `DoubleBuffered` enabled, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like problem is related to `Selected` / `Focused` combo (perhaps someone from Microsoft can confirm).

Here is a possible workaround (it's dirty and I liek it!):

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // before adding
        if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].Bounds.IntersectsWith(listView1.ClientRectangle))
                listView1.TopItem.Focused = true;
            else
                listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].Focused = true;
        }
        // add item
        listView1.VirtualListSize++;
    }
```

Trick is to check *before* adding new item whenever currently selected item is away ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339133/check-if-selected-item-is-visible-virtual-listview-in-details-view/18339719) is the topic of how to check). And if item is away, then set focus to the current `TopItem` temporarily (until user scroll back, so that selected item will be again "visible" and this is when it gets focus back).

Answer (score 1):

After some finding for a work-around, I realized that you **can't prevent flicker once you select an item**. I've tried using some `ListView` messages but fail. If you want to research more on this, I think you should pay some attention at `LVM_SETITEMSTATE` and maybe some other messages. After all, I thought of this idea, we have to prevent the user from selecting an item. So to fake a **selected item**, we have to do some custom drawing and faking like this:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
        public CustomListView(){
            SelectedIndices = new List<int>();
            OwnerDraw = true;
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
        public new List<int> SelectedIndices {get;set;}
        public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x1000 + 43) return;//LVM_SETITEMSTATE                
            else if (m.Msg == 0x201 || m.Msg == 0x202)//WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP
            {
                int x = m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0x00ff;
                int y = m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16;
                ListViewItem item = GetItemAt(x, y);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
                    {
                        if (!SelectedIndices.Contains(item.Index)) SelectedIndices.Add(item.Index);
                    }
                    else if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                    {
                        for (int i = Math.Min(SelectedIndex, item.Index); i <= Math.Max(SelectedIndex, item.Index); i++)
                        {
                            if (!SelectedIndices.Contains(i)) SelectedIndices.Add(i);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SelectedIndices.Clear();
                        SelectedIndices.Add(item.Index);
                    }
                    SelectedIndex = item.Index;                        
                    return;
                }                    
            }
            else if (m.Msg == 0x100)//WM_KEYDOWN
            {
                Keys key = ((Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32() & Keys.KeyCode);
                if (key == Keys.Down || key == Keys.Right)
                {
                    SelectedIndex++;
                    SelectedIndices.Clear();
                    SelectedIndices.Add(SelectedIndex);
                }
                else if (key == Keys.Up || key == Keys.Left)
                {
                    SelectedIndex--;
                    SelectedIndices.Clear();
                    SelectedIndices.Add(SelectedIndex);
                }
                if (SelectedIndex == VirtualListSize) SelectedIndex = VirtualListSize - 1;
                if (SelectedIndex < 0) SelectedIndex = 0;
                return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);                
        }
        protected override void OnDrawColumnHeader(DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
            base.OnDrawColumnHeader(e);
        }
        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;           
            base.OnDrawItem(e);
        }
        int i;
        protected override void OnDrawSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
        {                
            if (!SelectedIndices.Contains(e.ItemIndex)) e.DrawDefault = true;
            else
            {
                bool isItem = i == 0;
                Rectangle iBound = FullRowSelect ? e.Bounds : isItem ? e.Item.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.ItemOnly) : e.SubItem.Bounds;
                Color iColor = FullRowSelect || isItem ? SystemColors.HighlightText : e.SubItem.ForeColor;
                Rectangle focusBound = FullRowSelect ? e.Item.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire) : iBound;
                if(FullRowSelect || isItem) e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, iBound);                    
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, isItem ? e.Item.Text : e.SubItem.Text,
                    isItem ? e.Item.Font : e.SubItem.Font, iBound, iColor,
                    TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
                if(FullRowSelect || isItem) 
                  ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, focusBound);
            }
            i++;                
            base.OnDrawSubItem(e);
        }
}
```

**NOTE**: This code above will disable `MouseDown`, `MouseUp` (for Left button) and `KeyDown` event (for arrow keys), if you want to handle these events outside of your `CustomListView`, you may want to raise these events yourself. (By default, these events are raised by some code in or after `base.WndProc`).

There is still one case in which the user can select the item by `holding mouse down and drag to select`. To disable this, I think we have to catch the message `WM_NCHITTEST` but we have to catch and filter it on right condition. I've tried dealing with this but no luck. I hope you can do it. This is just a demo. However as I said, we seem unable to go another way. I think your problem is some kind of `BUG` in the `ListView` control.

### UPDATE

In fact I thought of `Focused` and `Selected` before but that's when I've tried accessing the `SelectedItem` with `ListView.SelectedItems` (That's wrong). So I didn't trying that approach. However after finding out that we can access the `SelectedItem` of a `ListView` in virtual mode via the `ListView.SelectedIndices` and `ListView.Items`, I think this solution is the most efficient and simple one:

```
int selected = -1;
bool suppressSelectedIndexChanged;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listView1.SuspendLayout();                
  if (selected > -1){
     ListViewItem item = listView1.Items[selected];
     Rectangle rect = listView1.GetItemRect(item.Index);
     suppressSelectedIndexChanged = true;                    
     item.Selected = item.Focused = !(rect.Top <= 2 || rect.Bottom >= listView1.ClientSize.Height-2);
     suppressSelectedIndexChanged = false;
  }
  listView1.VirtualListSize++;
  listView1.ResumeLayout(true);
}
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if (suppressSelectedIndexChanged) return;
   selected = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0 ? listView1.SelectedIndices[0] : -1;
}
```

**NOTE**: The code is just a demo for the case user selects **just 1 item**, you can add more code to deal with the case user selects **more than 1 item**.

Comment: When I discover this bug, I was using custom `ListView` with double buffering enabled. Just tried to apply your solution, it still flickers. Maybe word *flicker* is not the right one, it looks like `ListView` is trying to repaint self in 2 points - where selected item is and where is current view point is (defined by `TopItem`?). And constant switch between them (visible on a scroll bar) causing this *flickering*.

Comment: your problem is not easy to solve, I've tried some work-around however in virtual mode, even we can't access (read or write) any Properties of the ListView related to indices, Count, items...

Comment: well, it's not easy, but should be possible, i am working on one.

Comment: It is not the kind of problem that double-buffering solves, it is not actually a flicker issue.   The selected item is indeed the problem, it tries to keep it visible but is then defeated by the added item.  It jumps back and forth.

Comment: @Sinatr see my updated answer for a work-around. BTW I think when you `auto-scroll` the `ListView` that way, you should disable user from selecting an item. If that's the case, it's much simpler to do.

Comment: @KingKing, I appreciate an effort you have put into this, thanks. However, your solution looks way more complicated than one I've found yesterday by accident and it still have *issues*.I was thinking to simply remove selection from current item so if user scroll away, then he will have to select an item after again. But surprisingly this didn't work. And then I remember about `Focused`.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't know if your solution (if found) is OK now, but I have a simpler solution in my Update, it works OK. The `Selected Item` will be `deselected` when it's out of view, otherwise it will be `selected` again/back. (that's better than forcing user to re-select it manually).

Comment: @KingKing, thanks for the update, it looks more simple now. However I can't figure out what exactly are you doing? I see you track selected item and I see you set it to be `Focused` and `Selected` or not (at once?). Could you elaborate a little bit more why? What is the solution? To remove `Selected` and `Focused` when control is not visible? Why this way (using `GetItemRect`, then checking `Top` and `Bottom`) is better than one in my solution (using `Bounds` property and `Intersect`, which I think does same check)?

Comment: @Sinatr there is no difference between `Bounds` the the use of `GetItemRect`. Using `Top` and `Bottom` to check of course is better. About the `Focused` and `Selected`, both of these should be set to the same value together, otherwise it won't work (of course I've tested and saw that, not from my knowledge before).

Comment: @KingKing, Cảm ơn (thanks), but I like more own answer (it seems to work very well so far).

Comment: @Sinatr it's interesting that you know how to say thanks in `Vietnamese` :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the code of @Sinatr almost works perfect, however when the selected item is right on the top border of the listview, it starts jumping between the selected and the next item on each update.

I had to include the height of the column headers to the visibility test which solved the problem for me:

```
if (lstLogMessages.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
{
    Rectangle selectedItemArea = lstLogMessages.Items[lstLogMessages.SelectedIndices[0]].Bounds;
    Rectangle listviewClientArea = lstLogMessages.ClientRectangle;
    int headerHeight = lstLogMessages.TopItem.Bounds.Top;
    if (selectedItemArea.Y + selectedItemArea.Height > headerHeight && selectedItemArea.Y + selectedItemArea.Height < listviewClientArea.Height)   // if the selected item is in the visible region 
    {
        lstLogMessages.Items[lstLogMessages.SelectedIndices[0]].Focused = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lstLogMessages.TopItem.Focused = true;
    }
}

lstLogMessages.VirtualListSize = currentView.MessageCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old post and [King King] has already given a double buffer example but still posting a simple code if it helps some one & this also removes flickering even if you have a item selected, but you need to Inherit ListView to use this cause SetStyle is not accessible from outside

C# Code

```
public class ListViewEX : ListView
{
    public ListViewEX()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Public Class ListViewEX
    Inherits ListView
    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```