# Check if selected item is visible [virtual ListView in details view]

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, virtualmode

Is there any good/short solution to the subj?

I can think of:

- get `TopItem` index (in `VirtualMode` can it be null before item is created?), if index of needed item is less, then it is invisible, otherwise get bottom visible index (top index + `listView.ClientSize.Height / GetItemRect(TopItem).Height`) and if index of needed item is more, then it is invisible. Otherwise visible.
- detect scrolling somehow and do something.

Or maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
listView1.Items[SelectedItemIndex].Bounds.IntersectsWith(listView1.ClientRectangle)
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: `var visible = listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].Bounds.IntersectsWith(listView1.ClientRectangle)` and it perfectly works, thanks!